# Indent text cursor for input textbook

Tags: jquery, css

How to indent the text cursor of the textbox:

I used the following CSS code:

```
text-indent:8px;
```

But the first time the textbox is focused the indent doesn't apply, it only applies when someone types.
Is there another way to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use `padding-left` instead :)

```
padding-left:8px;
```